# Automatically create labels based on the number of database entry's c# asp.net mssql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is there a way to generate labels based on how many user entry's there are in a database and print the database information to the labels on page load.

I have attempted to do this by binding the data but i found i can only do this in a grid format and i don't want a grid.

What i am trying to create overall is a survey in which the questions are stored in the database and displayed on the labels. I want someone to be able to add a question to the database and a label to be automatically generated for it displaying the question.

I am able to get my desired effect but i have added labels and written the questions on them manually. If anyone can please help or advise if it can be done it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Here is what i have so far:

```
<h1>&nbsp;</h1>
    <h1>PaaS Assured Server Test</h1>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Panel ID="BugPanel1" runat="server" BorderColor="#FFFF99" BackColor="#FFFF99" Visible="False">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="You have informed us of an error." ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <br /><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Please advise of serverity. 1 - highest 5 - lowest:" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                   &nbsp; <asp:DropDownList ID="SeverityList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br /><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Who shall be notified of the error:" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp; <asp:DropDownList ID="NotifyList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserName] FROM [AspNetUsers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br /><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Would you like a copy emailed to yourself?" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="EmailRadio1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes">No</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:Button ID="BugButton" runat="server" Text="File Bug and Generate Report" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="BugButton_Click" />
                </asp:Panel>


                 </h2>
            <h2>Provisioning</h2>
        <hr />
            <asp:Panel ID="FormPanel1" runat="server" BackColor="#F4F4F4">
            <asp:Panel ID="HeadPanel1" runat="server" BackColor="#E4E4E4" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000066" Font-Underline="True">
            <h3>Page View</h3>
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Radio1Validator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error: Please select an option:" ControlToValidate="Radio1" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  <p />
            <asp:Label ID="PALabel1" runat="server" Text="Does your screen look similar to the image displayed ?"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/Info.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Width="21px" CausesValidation="False" /><br/>     
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:RadioButtonList>

                <asp:Panel ID="PAPanel1" runat="server">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#000099" Text="Provide further details:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PAText1" runat="server" BorderColor="Silver" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:Panel>
                <p />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Radio2Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Radio2" ErrorMessage="Error: Please select an option:" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <p />
                <asp:Label ID="PALabel2" runat="server" Text="In &quot;Server Name&quot; is virtual pre-selected?"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" height="20px" runat="server" Width="21px" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/Info.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton4_Click" />
            <br/>         
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:RadioButtonList>
           <asp:Panel ID="PAPanel2" runat="server">     
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Provide further details:" ForeColor="#000099"></asp:Label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="PAText2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" BorderColor="Silver"   ></asp:TextBox>
           </asp:Panel>

                <asp:Panel ID="HeadPanel2" runat="server" BackColor="#E4E4E4" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#000066" Font-Underline="True">
            <h3>Form details</h3>
            </asp:Panel>
                 <asp:Panel ID="SubHead1" runat="server" BackColor="#F3F3F3" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#003399" Font-Underline="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller">
            <h4>Request Details</h4>
            </asp:Panel>
                 <asp:Panel ID="SubHead2" runat="server" BackColor="#F3F3F3" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#003399" Font-Underline="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller">
            <h4>Server Location</h4>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="SubHead3" runat="server" BackColor="#F3F3F3" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#003399" Font-Underline="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller">
            <h4>Product and Support Details</h4>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="SubHead4" runat="server" BackColor="#F3F3F3" BorderColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#003399" Font-Underline="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Smaller">
            <h4>Server Configuration</h4>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Label ID="PALabel3" runat="server" Text="What operating system are you testing?"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/Info.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" Width="21px" CausesValidation="False" /><br/>         
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select the server you are testing:" ControlToValidate="Radio3" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Windows 2008 Server R2" Text="Windows 2008 Server R2">Windows 2008 Server R2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Windows 2012 Server R2" Text="Windows 2012 Server R2">Windows 2012 Server R2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="RHEL" Text="RHEL">RHEL</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
              <p />&nbsp;<p />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit"/>
                    <p />
                    &nbsp;</asp:Panel>



        </div>        




        <div class="col-md-6">
       <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>Information Viewer &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Image ID="LrgInfoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/Info.jpg" Height="21px" Width="24px" /> 
                &nbsp&nbsp<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="View test history" BorderColor="#ECECFF" BorderStyle="Ridge" CssClass="btn" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0066FF" Height="32px" OnClick="Button2_Click" Width="177px" CausesValidation="False" />
            </h2> <hr />
            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="View0" runat="server">
               <div style="overflow-x:auto;width:600px" class="fixed">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PAssuredId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" BorderColor="#F4F4F4" ForeColor="#000066" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="56%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F4F4FF" BorderColor="Black" ForeColor="#000066" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PAssuredId" HeaderText="Test ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PAssuredId" NullDisplayText="INVALID TEST" ItemStyle-BackColor="#F0F0FF" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date/ Time" SortExpression="Date" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="UserName" NullDisplayText="INVALID TEST" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Platform" HeaderText="Platform" SortExpression="Platform" NullDisplayText="User did not select platform" />
                            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="VirtualPreselect" HeaderText="Virtual" SortExpression="VirtualPreselect" />
                            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="DetsAccurate" HeaderText="Details ok?" SortExpression="DetsAccurate" />
                            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ScreenSame" HeaderText="Correct form?" SortExpression="ScreenSame" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="No1" HeaderText="Error 1" SortExpression="No1" NullDisplayText="No error found" ReadOnly="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="No2" HeaderText="Error 2" SortExpression="No2" NullDisplayText="No error found" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="No3" HeaderText="Error 3" SortExpression="No3" NullDisplayText="No error found" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="No4" HeaderText="Error 4" SortExpression="No4" NullDisplayText="No error found" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="No5" HeaderText="Error 5" SortExpression="No5" NullDisplayText="No error found" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>    
                    </div>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT PaaSAssuredServer.PAssuredId, PaaSAssuredServer.Date, AspNetUsers.UserName, PaaSAssuredServer.Platform, PaaSAssuredServer.VirtualPreselect, PaaSAssuredServer.DetsAccurate, PaaSAssuredServer.ScreenSame, PaaSAssuredServer.No1, PaaSAssuredServer.No2, PaaSAssuredServer.No3, PaaSAssuredServer.No4, PaaSAssuredServer.No5 FROM PaaSAssuredServer INNER JOIN AspNetUsers ON PaaSAssuredServer.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id ORDER BY PaaSAssuredServer.Date DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="ScreenImge" runat="server" Height="600px" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/PassTest1.jpg" Width="600px" />
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="105px" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/ServerType.jpg" Width="446px" />
                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/PrintScreen/ServerType.jpg" Height="105px" Width="446px" />
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>

        </div>
            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code behind :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;


namespace IRISTest
{
    public partial class PaaSAssuredServer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Radio1.SelectedValue == "False")
            {
                PAPanel1.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                PAPanel1.Visible = false;
            }

            if (Radio2.SelectedValue == "False")
            {
                PAPanel2.Visible = true;
            }

            else
            {
                PAPanel2.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        }

        protected void ImageButton4_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 3;
        }
        protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string message = "I can confirm the following:" + Environment.NewLine + "It is " + Radio1.SelectedValue + " that my screen matches that displayed in the image. " + Environment.NewLine +
                                  "It is:" + Radio2.SelectedValue + " that my default Server Name is set to Virtual. " + Environment.NewLine +
                                  "I have follwed the steps accurately and provided all requested information/ further details to enable further investigation" + Environment.NewLine +
                                  "On hitting sumbit I am confirming that I have perfomed this test and the provided information is accurate to my knowledge.";
                string caption = "Confirmation:";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                MessageBoxIcon icon = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
                MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultbutton = MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2;
                DialogResult result;

                result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon, defaultbutton);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                    Int32 newProdID = 0;

                    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

                    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [PaaSAssuredServer] ([VirtualPreselect], [No1], [No2], [ScreenSame], [Date], [UserId], [Platform]) VALUES ( @VirtualPreselect, @No1, @No2, @ScreenSame, @Date, @UserId, @Platform);" + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)");
                        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = connection;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScreenSame", Radio1.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VirtualPreselect", Radio2.SelectedItem.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No1", PAText1.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No2", PAText2.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", Radio3.SelectedItem.Value);
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", 0);
                        //cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                        connection.Open();
                        try
                        {

                            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            //int UserId = (int)cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value;

                            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            //var rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                            lblmsg.Text = "You have completed and recorded the test Sucessfully " + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Your test number is: " + newProdID;
                            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                        }

                        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                        {
                            lblmsg.Text = sqlEx.Message;
                            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }

                        finally
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                        if (PAText1.Text == "0")
                        {
                            BugPanel1.Visible = true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            BugPanel1.Visible = false;
                        }

                        if (PAText2.Text == "0")
                        {
                            BugPanel1.Visible = true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            BugPanel1.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void BugButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 newProdID1 = 0;

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var BugTest = true;


            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [BugRep] ([Bug], [Serverity], [CorrName], [UserId]) VALUES (@Bug, @Serverity, @CorrName, @UserId);" + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)");
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serverity", SeverityList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorrName", NotifyList1.SelectedItem.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bug", BugTest);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Platform", Radio3.SelectedItem.Value);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", 0);
                //cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
                connection.Open();
                try
                {

                    newProdID1 = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    //int UserId = (int)cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value;

                    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //var rowCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    lblmsg.Text = "You have reported the bug sucessfully and" + NotifyList1.SelectedItem.Value + "has been informed." + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Your test number is: " + newProdID1;
                    lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                }

                catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = sqlEx.Message;
                    lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }












        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track to use data binding. If you want to have more control over the HTML that is generated, you can use a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) control. This way, you can specify templates for the items you want to display.

The following sample shows a Repeater. In the ItemTemplate, a HiddenField stores the question id and a Label shows the text. When the page is requested, the items are retrieved from a database (the sample uses test data) and bound to the Repeater. I've also added a dropdown in the ItemTemplate so that the user can select an answer. Upon clicking the Save button, the values are retrieved from the controls in the items of the Repeater.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <p>
             <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
             <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' />
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnswer" runat="server">
                 <asp:ListItem Text="1" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="2" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="3" />
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </p>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

### Code Behind

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var questions = GetQuestions();
            rpt.DataSource = questions;
            rpt.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
    {
        // Load questions from database
        // Setting up some sample data for this sample
        var lst = new List<Question>();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Question() { Id = x, Text = "Question " + x.ToString() });
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dictAnswers = GetValuesFromRepeater();
        // Save answers to database
    }

    private IDictionary<int, int> GetValuesFromRepeater()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var id = int.Parse(((HiddenField)item.FindControl("hiddenId")).Value);
                var answer = int.Parse(((DropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlAnswer")).Text);
                dict.Add(id, answer);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that when retrieving the values from the repeater, the controls have to be found by their id using the `FindControl` method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I dont understand this piece:  { Id = x, Text = "Question " + x.ToString() });   What is the Id and Text supposed to do? Are they supposed to call from the ASPX?

Comment: @user3596726 in the `GetQuestions` method I put together some sample data. I use Enumerable.Range to get a range of int (1...5) and create a `Question` object for each. The part `{ Id = x, Text = "Question " + x.ToString() }` is used to set the values on the newly created `Question` object. In your case, you'd get the data from the database in this method. You can also bind the Repeater to a DataTable if this is easier.

Comment: I totally understand now I bound my data to the repeater and is working fine. You have made my day. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select fields from database", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataRow dr in DataSet.Tables[0].Rows){
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = dr["column"].ToString() + ":";
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "txt" + dr["id"].ToString();
}
```

You have to push it into *!IsPostBack*

On saving you have to take all IDs into some array or list, and use foreach array:

```
foreach (int id in id_array){
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@"+param+id.ToString(), (TextBox)(Page.FindControlById("txt"+id.ToString())).Text);
}
```

But you also have to think about your sql_query (in code-behind or stored procedure, make it responsive, depending on params number).
Hope it helps